# Creating Volume inddictor with volume bars in 3 colours

Tags: pine-script

I think about very simple Volume indicator for TradingView with 3 colour bars?: For Standard Volume it would be 3 bars: bullish, bearish and third pink volume bar lower than n previous volume bars. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, pink isn't a built-in color. You'd have to figure out the color code, or an easy workaround is to use purple.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © bajaco

//@version=4
study("Volume Bars")
n = input(title='n', type=input.integer, defval=3)
green = close > open
bar_color = volume < lowest(volume,n)[1] ? color.purple : green ? color.green : color.red
plot(volume, color=bar_color, style=plot.style_columns)
```